# How to use manipulate with ParametricPlot3D

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I am trying to visualize a straight-line homotopy between the sphere and the cube. I have parametrized the sphere and cube as

```
f[u_,v_] := {Sin[u] Cos[v], Sin[u] Sin[v], Cos[u]}
```

and

```
Subscript[S, q][u_,v_] := (1/Max[Abs[Sin[u] Cos[v]], Abs[Sin[u] Sin[v]], Abs[Cos[u]]]) f[u, v]
```

respectively. With t=0.5, the following gives me a surface halfway between a sphere and cube:

```
ParametricPlot3D[(1 - 0.5) Subscript[S, q][u, v] + 0.5 f[u, v], {u, 0,Pi}, {v, 0, 2Pi},PlotTheme -> "Classic", Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, Exclusions -> None]
```

In order to manipulate t, I wrote the following:

```
Manipulate[ParametricPlot3D[(1 - t) Subscript[S, q][u, v] + tf[u, v], {u, 0,Pi},{v,0,2Pi},PlotTheme -> "Classic", Axes -> False,Boxed -> False, Exclusions -> None], {t, 0,1}]
```

However, that just returns a blank plot. Where have I made a mistake? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[u_, v_] := {Sin[u] Cos[v], Sin[u] Sin[v], Cos[u]}

Subscript[S, q][u_, 
  v_] := (1/Max[Abs[Sin[u] Cos[v]], Abs[Sin[u] Sin[v]], Abs[Cos[u]]]) f[u, v]
```

You need to use `t*f` vice `tf`

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot3D[(1 - t) Subscript[S, q][u, v] + t*f[u, v],
  {u, 0, Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi},
  PlotTheme -> "Classic",
  Axes -> False,
  Boxed -> False,
  Exclusions -> None,
  SphericalRegion -> True,
  MaxRecursion -> 5],
 {{t, 0}, 0, 1, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 SynchronousUpdating -> False,
 TrackedSymbols :> {t}]
```

[image]